# MySQL select records hourly apart of eachother

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores times in quarters e.g. 9:00, 9:15, 9:30, 9:45, 10:00, 10:15 and so on.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM time_slots WHERE start_time > '9:00' AND end_time < '18:00'
```

I get all the records as expected, but I want to only return those that are only an hour apart of eachother e.g. I want to only get the following:

```
10:00

11:00

12:00

13:00

etc until 17:00
```

Excluding all others in between that may be there e.g. 10:15, 10:30.
And equally if the start_time was 9:15 then the rows returned should be 10:15, 11:15 so on. How can I achieve this?

Have added a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d7030/2/0)

Comment: What are columns of the table ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: updated and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the column of the table, maybe this do want you want :

Use LIKE '%:00' : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
SELECT *
FROM time_slots
WHERE (start_time > '9:00'AND start_time LIKE '%:00')
AND (end_time < '18:00' AND end_time LIKE '%:00')
```

Comment: This works upvoted, the problem with this is it isn't dynamic e.g. if I want the 15s then I will need to manually change the like clause e.g. `LIKE '%:15'`

Comment: It depend on what you are doing. You can hard code the value or pass a variable in the LIKE